# How can I show a Toast within Thread of a service implement LocatonListener?

Tags: android

I have class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener. Insinde onLocationChanged(), I have a thread and I want show a Toast "abc", how can I do that? Plz help me?

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude);  
        // update location here
        String regChildID = SharePreferenceData.getCheckedRegister(mContext);

            if ( regChildID.split(",")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                try {
                    String locationData;
                    String regID = regChildID.split(",")[2];
                    locationData = URLEncoder.encode("reg_child_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(regID.substring(0, regID.length()-1), "UTF-8");
                    locationData += "&" +  URLEncoder.encode("lat", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(latitude), "UTF-8");
                    locationData += "&" +  URLEncoder.encode("long", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(longitude), "UTF-8");
                    numberRequest = numberRequest +1;
                    final String data = locationData;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String response = HttpRequest.sendData(Def.HTTP_METHOD_POST, Def.LOCATION_API, data);
                            if (response != null) {
                                //Log.d(TAG, "Response from server: " + data);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Response from server: " + response);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Number request update: " + numberRequest);
                                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "asd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Number request update: " + "No response from server");
                            }
                        } 
                    }).start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
```

==================================> Update my solution

Thank everybody, I have just done it. I put context where I call in contructor class extends Service, and inside Thread I do like this code, thank @busylee

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             ...
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "abc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                             ...
                    }).start();
```

Comment: Not that I want to be the not-cool guy or anything, but are you sure about showing a Toast from a Service?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to define `Handler` inside thread you Service is running, and post `Runnable` to it. This code can helps you:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             ...
                             handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "asd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                             ...
                    }).start();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you but I still getting null when getApplicationContext!

Comment: thank you, instead of get ApplicationContext(), I put a context where I call this calss from contructor. It's work fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can Display a toast message Like that..

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


            //your code is here 


            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {


                        Toast.makeText(context, "Your messsage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                 



                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Code in question above runs inside Service. Where do you take MainActivity.this?

Comment: I know, but actually we cant runOnUI in a Service!